# PostgreSQL: Extract one word after a keyword from string

Tags: postgresql, substring, string-matching

I have a column in Postgres like below and I want to split only the character that comes next to the keyword. In the below case the keyword is

"Patient"

```
Patient Mark has tested positive
New update for Patient Wilson 
Discharged - Patient Thompson
```

The result column I need should be like

```
Mark
Wilson
Thompson
```

Comment: None of your sample values contain the keyword `product` - did you mean `Patient`?

Comment: probably keyword is "Patient"

Comment: I am sorry, yes the keyword is patient, I have updated

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data is in column called str

try following query

```
SELECT 
  substring(split_part(str, 'Patient', 2) from '[^ ]+'::text) as patient_name 
FROM 
  table_name
;
```

Comment: Getting error while executing the query   Reason:
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Not implemented
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Not implemented
  code:      1001
  context:   'false' - Function substring(text,text) not implemented - use REGEXP_SUBSTR instead
  query:     75899630
  location:  cg_expr_fn_builder.cpp:4510
  process:   padbmaster [pid=31188]

Comment: Its working, check this fiddle, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ad3bb3cd290896ebeda2978ff678cbda

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regexp_matches](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-regexp_matches/) function. For example :

```
SELECT regexp_matches('Patient Mark has tested positive', 'Patient (\S+)');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {Mark}
(1 row)

SELECT regexp_matches('New update for Patient Wilson', 'Patient (\S+)');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {Wilson}
(1 row)

SELECT regexp_matches('Discharged - Patient Thompson', 'Patient (\S+)');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {Thompson}
(1 row)
```

In this case regular expression `'Patient (\S+)'` returns all not space characters follows after keyword Patient until next space or end of string